# I'm trying to building an action method that accept comma separated list of fields and then orderBy an entity by it using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to building an asp.net API action method that accept comma separated list of fields and then orderBy an entity by it using reflection

**Code:**

```
public IActionResult orderBy([FromQuery] string fields)
{
    string[] _fields = fields.Split(',');
    try {
        PropertyInfo[] Props = _fields.Select(field => typeof(Product).GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ).ToArray();

        var query = _context.Product
                          .AsNoTracking()
                          .OrderBy(p => Props.First().GetValue(p));

        for (int i = 1; i < Props.Count(); i++)
            query = query.ThenBy(p => Props[i].GetValue(p));

        return Ok( query.ToList() );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return BadRequest(new { Title = ex.GetType().Name, Error = ex });
    }
}
```

and I got that **exception**

> IndexOutOfRangeException "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
>   on that line return Ok( query.ToList() );

what's the error ???

Comment: Most probably `_fields` contain one or none values. hence the `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you're calling `Props[1]` (first iteration of the for loop).

Comment: i know i should test the Props count first 
but I test it with two or more fields 
and the exception happend

Comment: Did you try to debug it? How many items do you see in _fields array?

Comment: Same question about Props collection

Comment: Yes I see both collections and they working as they should
and the query orderBy proceed with no complaint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the `i` inside the for loop for it work.

Change your for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Props.Count(); i++)
{
    var capturedI = i;
    query = query.ThenBy(p => Props[capturedI].GetValue(p));
}
```

To varify the problem you can adjust your code to this and you will see the output of `i` when the `.ThenBy` gets exectued upon `.ToList()`

```
for (int i = 1; i < Props.Count(); i++)
{
    //.ThenBy is lacy and will not execute here - and because of that the current value of i is irrelevant
    query = query.ThenBy(p =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        return Props[i].GetValue(p);
    });
}

return Ok( query.ToList() ); //the .ToList() will NOW trigger the query and execute the .ThenBys with i = Props.Count()
```

Comment: I accepted the answer but because of my reputation it does't change public vote

Comment: @Ahmady013 I believe you are confussing accepting an answer and voting for an answer - your reputation shouldnt be of concern when accepting an answer - have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

hi @Ahmady013 : can you try below controller action. this one should work

```
public IActionResult orderBy([FromQuery] string fields)
{
  string[] _fields = fields.Split(',');
  try {
  PropertyInfo[] Props = _fields.Select(field => typeof(Product).GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ).ToArray();

  var query = _context.Product
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .OrderBy(p => Props.First().GetValue(p));

  for (int i = 0; i < Props.Count(); i++)
    query = query.ThenBy(p => Props[i].GetValue(p));

    return Ok( query.ToList() );
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    return BadRequest(new { Title = ex.GetType().Name, Error = ex });
  }
}
```